# What do you call a person who doesn't keep his word?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What do you call a person who doesn't/can't usually keep his/her word ?

Comment: What about *traitor*?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you should check out "disloyal" or "not trustworthy"

Comment: Actually I wanted to put more emphasis on "CAN NOT" portion of my question. A person who CAN NOT keep his word. Traitor sounds intentional and disloyal as well. "RENEGER" as mentioned in another post sounds quite close to what I want - maybe so

Comment: A "politician".

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A liar** if you want a simple term.

If it is someone who regularly makes promises and doesn't live up to them they are a [**renegger**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=reneging).

You may also see a moderately offensive (to some) term [**Indian Giver**](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_giver) which is a reference to Native Americans.  This term was very popular before the PC movement.

And if it is someone who doesn't pay their bets they are a [**welcher**](http://i.word.com/idictionary/welch).

Comment: Liar implies deception when there may be none intended so I don't think that's a good fit, IMO.  Indian giver isn't really appropriate either since it's not someone who backs out of a promise, it is someone who takes something back that they've given you (in its generally understood usage). Renegger and welcher are good, though! :-)

Comment: I dare you to use the word renegger where I am from!

Comment: @Ryebread That's a pronunciation issue!

Comment: I dare you to pronounce it right too.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I would argue that not keeping your promises is a lie. It's not like you'd call this person a bald-faced liar, but you wouldn't call what they're doing truthful either.  It's like a sin of omission, it's still a sin.

Comment: @ryebread It's a funny comment, but you're not giving people enough credit.  I pronounce it like the end of Schwarzenegger.  With negg rhyming with egg.

Comment: I understand but I am being DEAD serious.  Not even kidding.  Please go about a mile from my house and use that term.

Comment: @RyeBread, context, context, context!  Standing on a street corner yelling "Renegger!" is bound to cause trouble. :-)

Comment: @DavidM, I agree that it's a type of sin, just not the commonly accepted definition of a lie which implies intent to deceive.

Comment: @KristinaLopez "You've lied to me."  "I didn't mean to."  "Well, it was still a lie."  You've never had that conversation before?

Comment: @KristinaLopez - I disagree.  Context is worse.  "Dude you said you were going to bring back the stuff yesterday."  "Sorry bro, I will get it to you tomorrow."  "You are a renegger!"  #%&#($&(#&$(#(#$&(#$$&#($&#$(#$(&#($#$&(#$&

Comment: @DavidM - those are the best words.  Would upvote but might get hand slapped for upvoting a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidM, If someone said "you lied to me", it would not be true if what I said was the truth at the time I said it but something changed that, either outside circumstances, or even if I changed my mind, unless the "lie" was originally said, ***with the intent to deceive***, it's technically not a lie.  If you would have included the dictionary definition for "lie", as included here, you'd see the prerequisite of the intent to deceive: Definition of LIE (from MWO): *intransitive verb, 1: to make an untrue statement with intent to deceive 2: to create a false or misleading impression*

Comment: 5 years later, came across this. To "renege" comes from the word renegāre which is Latin for renegade. It has nothing to do with other slang and should be defended as such.

Answer (score 5):

I would usually call them a Flake.

**Edit:**
Per David M's Request:

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=flake)

> n. An unreliable person; someone who agrees to do something, but
>   never follows through.
>   1. John called in sick to work again today. He's such a flake.
>    2. Mary said she would do the research for our project, but it's been a week and she hasn't done a thing. She's such a flake.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flake)

> -5.   slang chiefly  ( US ) an eccentric, crazy, or unreliable person

Comment: That is a good one, too. But, can you provide a definition or reference just for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Such a person is 'untrustworthy'

Answer (score 1):

A **"welcher"** is someone who backs out of a commitment.  Since it's origin may refer to the Welsh people, this may be considered offensive.

Per [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/welsher), from the verb "welsh" or "welch":

> verb (used without object)
>
> Informal: Sometimes Offensive.
>
> 1. to cheat by failing to pay a gambling debt: You aren't going to welsh on me, are you?
> 2. to go back on one's word: He welshed on his promise to help in the campaign.
>
> Origin:  1855–60;  perhaps special use of Welsh

Comment: Yeah, Welsh bashing has been a major issue of late!  ;-P  Actually, this might make a great question:  what are some commonly used terms with racist origins.

Answer (score 0):

A **promise-breaker** would probably have the clearest meaning of them all, but it's not the 'one word' you might be looking for. **Reneger** is a good alternative.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reneger